# Can't figure out how to change default download folder with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried several advices ChatGPT gave me but not one of them worked - the files that I download from websites are still saved to Downloads folder. What am I doing wrong?

This is how I set up the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip

chrome_options = Options()
# Set download directory
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\Selenium\\",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})

# Create Chrome driver with options
webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
```

I tried the code above and this:

```
# Find the downloaded file and move it to a different directory with a new name
for fname in os.listdir(download_dir):
    if fname.endswith('.xlsx'):
        src_path = os.path.join(download_dir, fname)
        dest_path = r'C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\NewName.xlsx'
        os.rename(src_path, dest_path)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not passing chrome options in below in your code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe") driver.maximize_window()
```

try below code and Update path to your download folder below

```
  chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": "path to folder",
                                                     "download.prompt_for_download": False,
                                                     "download.directory_upgrade": True, "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
    driver.maximize_window()
// DO some action to download file
    time.sleep(5)
```